# Why do I get request staus 400 even though the url is okay

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension which calls a website and then extracts some data from it. It worked pretty fine all the time but suddenly I get a resonse state of 400 with this code:

main.js:

```
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest;

 request.open("GET", "https://www.mydomain.de/mypage.hml", true);
 request.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
     if (request.status == 200) {

        giftUrl = extractData(request.response);
    }
    else
        console.log("request state " + request.status);
});

request.send(null);
```

When I copy the url into my browser then the page is shown without any problems. What could be the reason for state 400 if the browser can display the url?

My mainifest:

```
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": [
    "http://*.mydomain.de/*",
    "https://*.mydomain.de/*"
  ],
  "js": [ "MyScript.js" ],
  "run_at": "document_end"
}
],
 "background": {
  "scripts": [ "jQuery.js", "main.js" ],
  "persistent": false
},
"permissions": [
  "https://*.mydomain.de/",
  "alarms",
  "cookies",
  "tabs",
  "unlimitedStorage",
  "http://*/*",
  "https://*/*"
]
```

the

Comment: If this is inside a content script, modern Chrome doesn't allow fetching of cross-origin URLs, see [CORB explainer](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches) for workarounds. Otherwise it could be something the site's server does when it detects the request is made by an extension, but I can't be sure without seeing all actually sent headers for the request.

Comment: Since my extension only works when you get to the page www.mydomain.de and the called url is request.open("GET", "https://www.mydomain.de/mypage.html", true); I don't think it is cross origin, is it?

Comment: Ì may add it is in the background script

Comment: if it is something on the server detecting the request is from an extension, can I do something about it so that it looks like as if it is from a browser? Maybe some header content?

Comment: Compare your request's headers to some native site's request in devtools and see if there's any difference.

Comment: what do you mean with devtools? is this an addon for chrome?

Comment: This is a [built-in debugging tool](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/). BTW You can use google search to lookup terms like that.

Answer (score 0):

you need to request cross origin permissions
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

> By adding hosts or host match patterns (or both) to the permissions section of the manifest file, the extension can request access to remote servers outside of its origin.

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "https://www.google.com/"
  ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't change someting